# Choosing layer orders on an Android app screen

Tags: javascript, android, webview

This is about a screen on an android app , have two layers, the layers can be selected and deselected by a layer list button. The problem we are facing is, we are not being able to control the order of the layers . We would want one layer to be on the top of the other always. Which parameter will help us in controlling this ?

Comment: XML : Just order them from bottom to front.

Programmatically : view.bringToFront()

Comment: the layer can be dynamically selected and de-selected by the customer from the checkbox . The user can selected layer1 and then layer2 or vice - versa
But we want the one to always be the back ground layer and the other to be the foreground.